# How to add "select" in dojo tooltipdialog content programmatically?

Tags: select, dojo, tooltip

I want to display `dojo select` inside a **dijit/TooltipDialog**. The items of the `dojo select` are dynamically loaded. So I want to add this **`select`** programmaticaly. The content of **TooltipDialog** can be an object but select needs a domNode to be held. The code is :

```
<head>
    <script>
        require([
            "dojo/parser",
            "dijit/form/Select",
            "dijit/TooltipDialog",
            "dojo/on",
            "dojo/dom",
            "dojo/_base/lang",
            "dijit/popup",
            "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(parser,Select,TooltipDialog,on,dom,lang,popup, ObjectStore, Memory){
            parser.parse();
            var t={mySel:null};



            var store = new Memory({
                data: [
                    { id: "foo", label: "Foo" },
                    { id: "bar", label: "Bar" }
                ]
            });

            var os = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: store });

            t.mySel = new Select({
                store: os
            }, "ttt");
            var myTooltipDialog = new TooltipDialog({
                content: t,
                onMouseLeave: function(){
                    popup.close(myTooltipDialog);
                }
            });
            on(dom.byId("mmm"),"mouseover" ,lang.hitch(this,function(e){

                popup.open({
                    popup: myTooltipDialog,
                    orient: ["above-centered","above","below"],
                    around:dom.byId('mmm')

                });
                t.mySel.startup();
            }));
            t.mySel.on("change", function(){
                console.log("my value: ", this.get("value"))
            })

        })
    </script>

</head>
<body class="claro">

    <div id="ttt"  >  tttt</div><br>
    <div id="mmm"  >  tttt</div><br>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you need smt like this? Could you please elaborate more your question? https://jsfiddle.net/bbwtraeo/

Comment: You have almost got it correct. Just change the line `content: t,` to `content: t.mySel,`. It should work. However, when you try to change the option in dropdown with mouse, the onMouseLeave event occurs and you wouldn't be able to change it. You could change the option with keyboard though.

Comment: As @TKambi suggested, `content: t.mySel` will make the magic. Also, if you are going to place your select within a tooltip, you don't need to place it in the DOM to create it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.  If I have more controls, fore example: two radio buttons and one select. How to add them in tooltipdialog and how to layout them in the dialog?

Comment: Furthermore, how to avoid the onMouseLeave event fired when select changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assignign an object t the tooltip content not a domenode

so try to make these change :

```
var myTooltipDialog = new TooltipDialog({
    content: t.mySel.domNode,
    onMouseLeave: function() {
        popup.close(myTooltipDialog);
    }
}
```